# Laravel belongsTo relation returns null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm having trouble with the Laravel BelongsTo relation.

I want to loop through a collection of cooks and get meals from them.

I create the cooks collection like this:
`$cooks = Cook::has('meals')->get();`

Then I want to get the meals like this in a foreach loop:

```
foreach($cooks as $cook){
    $meals = $cook->meals()->get()
}
```

But the meals get stuck on the following function:

```
public function getCookNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->cook->userProfile->firstname . ' ' . $this->cook->userProfile->lastname;
    }
```

I get the error that cook is null, but how is that possible if the query is run from the cook?

The relation looks like this:

```
public function cook(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cook::class);
    }
```

Comment: do this foreach($cooks as $cook){
    dd($cook);
}   if it print $cook then you do               foreach($cooks as $cook){
    dd($cook->meals);
}

Comment: and second you made this function in cook model ?   public function getCookNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->cook->userProfile->firstname . ' ' . $this->cook->userProfile->lastname;
    }

Comment: Youre problem is not with the relationship. You must have one cook that either doesnt have a userProfile or a userProfile who hasnt got the firstname or lastname attributes save in the database. They way you set it up will work but its bad practice to guess that everything has everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is right now when you do

```
  $meals = $cook->meals()->get();
```

You'll get a collection back containing only meals that belong to the cook, not also the cook, which is why the cook is null in your function.

Either you need to add a ->with('cook') to your first ->get() function but generally I wouldn't recommend having a database query in a loop. Otherwise you could do

```
 return $this->cook()->get()->userProfile->firstname . ' ' . $this->cook()->get()->userProfile->lastname;
```

but then you'll perform a query every time you are looking for the first and the last name.

Maybe get the cooks with their meals in one query in stead and then loop through the results:

```
$cooks = Cook::with('meals')->get();
echo($cooks);
```

The look at the results you get back and loop through them to get the cook name and their respective meals?

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I discovered the problem was in a query I did which I thought cloned the original query, but because I used a select() in the second query it ruined the original query

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with the foreign key and owner key?

```
public function cook()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cook::class, 'cook_id', 'id');
}
```

[Eloquent One To One Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Answer (score 0):

Use eager loading: [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```php
$cooks = Cook::with("meals.cook.userProfile")
    ->has('meals')
    ->get();

foreach($cooks as $cook){
    $meals = $cook->meals;
}
```

Then change your Model Accessor to:

```php
public function getCookNameAttribute()
{
    return trim(
        ($this->cook?->userProfile?->firstname ?? '')
        . ' '
        . ($this->cook?->userProfile?->lastname ?? '')
    );
}
```